# Google Sheet Query Error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am getting this error message on my query formula

> "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC"

and I don't know what seems to be the problem. I already change the format of column C to percentage but I'm still getting the same error.

```
=Query('Sheet1'!A1:C, "select A, avg(C), count(C) group by A,C", 1)
```

Sample Data:

```
 Date      | Name | CSAT %|
-----------|------|-------|
 2017-10-22| asdf |   100%|
 2017-10-15| qwer |   50% |
 2017-10-08| zxcv |   75% |
 2017-10-01| qwer |   90% |
```

Comment: Here is the actual file that I'm working on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iq9WgpMQ0_FI5g35ovZZWS4b01ozGh-QeBI7MzcELPA/edit#gid=2145808422

Answer (score 1):

One column of numerical data in my sheet would not register as numbers, no matter what (you can test this with function `N()`. It will show `0` for data which isn't considered numerical).

I fixed this with an extra column which added 0 to my numerical column. Even though the original column wasn't considered numerical, this somehow worked.

Answer (score -5):

I finally solved the puzzle using this:

```
=arrayformula(query({'Sheet1'!A:N, arrayformula(if(ISBLANK('Sheet1'!O:O), -1, value('Sheet1'!O:O)))
```

Basically, I put -1 on blank spaces in between rows and then on my query, I placed a condition to include only rows that have a value of >=0.

Comment: You have an open curly brace in your answer, but no close, so how would that ever work?

Comment: This was just part of the entire formula that's why it isn't complete.

Comment: In order to be of help to others it would be great if you would include the entire formula, I'm struggling with a similar problem.